# Shaka Player picking low quality variant at startup

Tags: video, video-streaming, shaka

When ABR is enabled, playback starts with the selected track but quickly jumps to lowest bitrate track in shaka player:

**Expected**

Track (track [id=14]) should be selected and continued in the same track when bandwidth available.

**What I tried**

Initially i tired setting abr.defaultBandwidthEstimate as 1927692 (track [id=14]) on manifestparsed event, but it picked the next track (track [id=13]). So i did following to find defaultBandwidthEstimate.

defaultBandwidthEstimate = selectedTrack.bandwidth / abr.bandwidthUpgradeTarget

defaultBandwidthEstimate = 1927692 / 0.85

then, the player picked the required track (track [id=14]).

**Problem**

Playback starts with the required track (track [id=14]) but immediately after few milliseconds fallback to lowest bandwidth track.
I also observed current estimated bandwidth from player was very low.

**Switch History:**

```
[{"timestamp":1595138570.405,"id":14,"type":"variant","fromAdaptation":true,"bandwidth":1927692},
{"timestamp":1595138570.405,"id":2,"type":"text","fromAdaptation":true,"bandwidth":null},
{"timestamp":1595138578.943,"id":10,"type":"variant","fromAdaptation":true,"bandwidth":295971}]
```

**All tracks**

```
[{id: 16, active: false, type: "variant", bandwidth: 5127146, language: "fr", …},
{id: 15, active: false, type: "variant", bandwidth: 2559584, language: "fr", …},
{id: 14, active: false, type: "variant", bandwidth: 1927692, language: "fr", …},
{id: 13, active: false, type: "variant", bandwidth: 1327795, language: "fr", …},
{id: 12, active: false, type: "variant", bandwidth: 695902, language: "fr", …},
{id: 11, active: false, type: "variant", bandwidth: 527931, language: "fr", …},
{id: 10, active: true, type: "variant", bandwidth: 295971, language: "fr", …}]
```

Answer (score 4):

ShakaPlayer provides us the configuration to restrict the minimum it can go for a given manifest/Internet. you can try the below to restrict the ABR to switch bit rates higher than given minBitratePixelValue.

```
 shakaPlayer.configure({
            restrictions: {
                minPixels: minBitratePixelValue,
                minHeight: minBitratePixelValue
            }
```

Hope this helps :)